# Bash: erase character in a given position

Tags: bash, position, format, character, output

I want to format the output of uptime command:

**13:28:07 up  1:04,  2 users,  load average: 0.66, 0.56, 0.59**

to this format:

**13:23 0.56 0.38 0.56**

erasing the numbers that represents seconds, now piping tr and cut I've got this string:

**13:23:05 0.56 0.38 0.56**

This is the reason because I want to know how to erase character in certain position of a string. 13:23:05 => 13:23
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
uptime | awk -F: '{printf "%s:%s%s\n", $1, $2, $NF}' | tr -d ,
```

gives me

```
 11:43 0.31 0.71 0.75
```

(with the leading space)

Answer (score 1):

```
uptime |sed 's/:[0-9][0-9]\s.*://'
 23:07 0.52, 0.59, 0.51
```

if you want to remove the `, (comma)` too:

```
uptime |sed 's/:[0-9][0-9]\s.*://;s/,//g'
 23:07 0.52 0.59 0.51
```